# StripeTextUtils Android

Tags: android

Buena tarde!! estoy empezando a desarrollar en android en el cual me pasaron un proyecto, en el viene con una libreria StripeText y en uno de los metodos me marca un error de que no puede usar clases privadas de la libreria antes mencionada.

La libreria que se usa.

```
import com.stripe.android.StripeTextUtils;
```

Este es mi codigo donde el error lo marca en hasAnyPrefix

```
public String getType(String number) {
    if (!StripeTextUtils.isBlank(number)) {
        if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_AMERICAN_EXPRESS)) {
            return AMERICAN_EXPRESS;
        } else if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_DISCOVER)) {
            return DISCOVER;
        } else if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_JCB)) {
            return JCB;
        } else if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_DINERS_CLUB)) {
            return DINERS_CLUB;
        } else if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_VISA)) {
            return VISA;
        } else if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_MASTERCARD)) {
            return MASTERCARD;
        } else {
            return UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
    return UNKNOWN;
}
```

Error que marca

```
Error:(332, 32) error: hasAnyPrefix(String,String...) is not public in StripeTextUtils; cannot be accessed from outside package
```

Espero puedan ayudarme o darme alguna idea de como solucionarlo, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `hasAnyPrefix` no es público, por lo tanto no está diseñado para que sea consumido desde afuera de la librería.

Stripe contiene un método público `getPossibleCardType` de la clase `CardUtils` que recibe un número y retorna el posible tipo de tarjeta. Este método llama internamente a la función `hasAnyPrefix`.

Puedes utilizarlo así:

```
String posibleTipoDeTarjeta = CardUtils.getPossibleCardType(number);
```

Si quieres revisar la lógica que implementa internamente el método `getPossibleCardType`, puedes encontrarla en GitHub en el [código fuente](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/v5.0.0/stripe/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/CardUtils.java) del archivo.

Comment: Gracias se soluciono el problema

Comment: Que bueno @UlisesDíaz! Si te sirvió la respuesta, podrías marcarla como respuesta aceptada, así otras personas podrán encontrarla de forma más fácil.

Answer (score 0):

posiblemente te esté faltando cargar/compilar la libreria StripeText. Para ello debes el archivo gradle (correspondiente a la app) poner la linea siguiente:

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:5.0.0'
```

Esto hará que gradle cargue dicha librería en la parte de `dependencies`y posiblemente se solucione tu problema.

Ej: (parte del archivo gradle)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:5.0.0'
}
```

Si el problema reside, tal vez debas plantearte para que se usa dicha librería y buscar otra o hacer tu los "cálculos" a mano.

Te adjunto enlace al proyecto de la librería. [StripeText](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android)